# Django hosted on Apache - Uploading a file going to wrong location

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a simple website that allows the user to upload a file to my server. I want the file to be uploaded into my django project folder in a sub directory.

Everything is working fine but when I use the upload feature on my website I get a permissions denied on the folder /var/www BUT the thing is I changed the DocumentRoot to equal /mnt/public/apps - which is where I want my uploaded files to go (the upload creates a sub directory).

I have correct permissions in /mnt/public but I can't figure out how to point django or apache so that my upload goes to the /mnt/public/apps root instead of /var/www

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you set [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#media-root) in your settings?

Comment: Could you show us your Apache `.conf` file (where you should have something like `Alias /media/ /mnt/public/apps/`) and the lines of your `settings.py` file containing media information (where you should specify the directory where the files are uploaded) ?

Comment: Django does not take any account of the DocumentRoot; the upload location will be set by the Django settings themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Alasdair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113962/alasdair) said in the comments, which was a super quick reply (thanks!), the correct fix for my problem was to add the MEDIA_ROOT variable to my settings.py file.